# Asp.Net MVC Program error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Why below error is coming in code ? What I do?

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    Emp emp = from c in db.Emps.Where(e => e.EmpId == id).Select(c).SingleOrDefault();
    EmpModel model = new EmpModel()
    {
        EmpId = emp.EmpId,
        EmpName=emp.EmpName,
        EmpJob=emp.EmpJob,
        EmpSalary=emp.EmpSalary,
        DeptId=emp.DeptId
    };
    return View(emp);
}
```

> Errors:
>
> 1)The name 'c' does not exist in the current context Error:
>
> 2) A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

[Click here to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kR5s.jpg)

Comment: Show your code. A link to an image is not acceptable here.- [I downvoted because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and include the details of the code and in the error _as text within your question_, thanks.

Comment: ok. thank you for help to improve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `from c in` part for this syntax, and you can simplify the rest quite a bit as well:

```
Emp emp = db.Emps.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmpId == id);
```

Comment: Thanks ADyson, ramadoss and ARr0w. 
Your suggestion are also work successfully in my code. 
But following query clear my error without changing my mentioned query after discussing with my class teacher. Please see following comment.

Comment: Emp emp = (from c in db.Emps.Where(e => e.EmpId == id) select c).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: That's true it would work, but why write more when you can write less? :-)

Comment: Now, I have very little knowledge of LINQ. I am first time learning it in asp.Net MVC. You are correct that if shortcut is available, then there is not need of long-cut. I like your way of writing LINQ query in short. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. The way you were doing is mixing Linq-to-SQL with Linq-to-Entities which have slightly different syntaxes. Usually it's not necessary to mix the two. Linq to SQL is a little more like native SQL, Linq to entities is more directly based on the C# objects which entity framework generates. Generally you can do the same things with each syntax and you shouldn't need or want to combine them like you were doing.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have used the `select` extended method which requires you to select needed fields that you want in your `Emp` object. By the way you Don't really need to use `From a in db` when you are using LINQ Query Syntax

for example:

```
   Emp EmpObj = Db.Emps.Where(e => e.EmpId == id).Select(x => x.EmpName).SingleOrDefault();
```

This select query will return only one specific value. But if you need multiple parameters out from it. You can return an object from `Select` extended Method like this:

```
.Select(x => new {x.Name, x.Address, x.Gender} ).SingleOrDefault();
```

Hope that helps and Please, before you question again do read; [How should i ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
EmpModel model = db.Emps.Where(e => e.EmpId == id).Select(x => new EmpModel { EmpId=x.EmpId , EmpName =x.EmpName, EmpJob =x.EmpJob, EmpSalary=x.EmpSalary, DeptId=x.DeptId }).SingleOrDefault();
```